# Passport Slack OAuth Scope Throwing Error with Identity

Tags: express, passport.js, slack-api

I'm trying to request a slack oauth token using the `passport-slack` module with the following code.

```
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
    clientID: xxxxxxx,
    clientSecret: xxxxxxx,
    scope: [
        'chat:write:user',
        'channels:read'
    ],
    callbackURL: xxxxxxx+"/slack/callback"
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    done(null, profile);
  }
));

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get('/authorize', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('Slack', function(err, user, info) {
    next();
  })(req, res, next);
});

/* OAuth Callback flow */
router.get('/callback', passport.authorize('Slack', { failureRedirect: '/authorize' }), function(req, res) {

});
```

However, I am getting the following response `"missing_scope","needed":"identity.basic","provided":"identify,channels:read,chat:write:user"}`.

But when I add `identify.basic` as a scope it errors saying I can't request both the identity and other scopes at the same time. Anyone know how to resolve this? I just want to generate an oauth token so my api can post to slack as a user.